# CouchDB: Do I need PHP at all?

Tags: couchdb

If I use couchDB with a Javascript webpage. Do I still need PHP?

How about authentication? Can this all be done with couchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PHP to work with CouchDB since there are [several](https://github.com/lenalena/couchdb-http-api-docs) JavaScript based [client](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/www/script/jquery.couch.js) [libraries](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqcouch) or you can try to look at [couchapp](http://couchapp.org/page/index).